# Django update model with unique field

Tags: python, django

I am trying to allow users to edit a topic. Whenever I try to update the topic I get the following error:

Title: Topic with this Title already exists.

```
# views.py
...
def post(self, request, title):
    topic = Topic.objects.all().get(title=title)
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if (form.is_valid()):
        topic.update(
            title=form.cleaned_data('title'),
            tags=form.cleaned_data('tags'),
        )
        return redirect('/topics/' + topic.title)
    else:
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'topic': topic, 'form': form})

# models.py
class Topic(models.Model):
    ...
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    ...

# forms.py
class EditTopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = [
            'title',
            'tags',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'tags': TagWidget(),
        }
```

Comment: Remove `unique=True`.

Comment: It looks like you're using `title` as some sort of primary key. I'd advise against this. Use the inbuilt `id` field instead.

Comment: Yes because people love figuring out if it was topic 23231 or topic 40093 they visited last time. How can I do this and still use the topic title in the url structure like say reddit

Comment: @mei you'll notice that reddit urls are actually unqiue and have a prefix: `https://www.reddit.com/r/news/comments/6q4ksf/north_korea_launches_ballistic_missile/`. The `6q4ksf` is actually the ID of the thread, and `north_korea_launches_ballistic_missile` is the name of it. And the Title is complete separate.

Comment: Thank you, that explains what I did wrong and gives a solution to the problem. Would mark as answer if I could

Comment: A quick question to follow up. Just like reddit the site I'm working on will have boards (like r/whatever). These boards do not have id's in front of them so what should I do if I ever want to edit one of the boards names?

Answer (score 1):

It will keep giving you that error report as long as you have `unique=True`
what I did was to remove `unique=True` from the model field,
and made my check on the views.py in create view class:

```
from django.contrib import messages
```

`if form.is_valid():
    topic = Topic.objects.all()
    title_checker = form.cleaned_data['title']
    for title in topic:
        if title == title_checker:
           messages.info(self.request, "THIS TITLE ALREADY EXISTS!!")
            return redirect('your-topic-create-page')`

with this, no existing topic title can be created, and you can easily update *if you do not put the checker snippet code in your update view*

Comment: Thank you. This gave me the idea of trapping the error in a form.